# How do I map a customer's domain to a page in my website?

Tags: domains, subdomain, ip-address

I'm considering starting a website that allows customers to map a domain they own and control, to their page or subdomain in my site. Do I need to have an IP address for each customer domain? Is this something that webhosts will commonly allow me to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're talking about, at least on Apache web server, are called Virtual Hosts. Your customers/clients would simply need to point the A record for their domain at your server's IP address where you have the Virtual Hosts setup.

In your Apache configuration, you'll need to setup a new Virtual Host for each new domain you have coming in, which you can then send to whatever location on your server you desire.

This isn't the place for a full Virtual Hosts tutorial, but there are [some good questions here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/virtualhost), and there's always the [Apache Virtual Host Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) or the [Apache Virtual Host Examples](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: Thanks Nathan. I'm only exploring possibilities now and this one certainly looks promising. I can't confirm yet that this one works for me, so I wanted to upvote it instead of checking it, however I don't have enough karma to do an upvote.  For now, accept my gratitude :) and a promise to either upvote when I earn enough karma or check it once I get it working!

Comment: The more I look into it, the more I find that confirmation on what you've shared, so I've put in the check. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There's lots of ways to skin a cat here. Just use an `.htaccess` redirect in the root of their domain:

```
## 301 Redirect Old File
Redirect 301 / yourdomain.com/somepage.html
```

Or make a simple index page with a redirect in the [header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

```
<?php header('Location: http://www.example.com/'); ?>
```

Then place it in the root of their domain.

Comment: So this means a customer will still need a separate host, they can't just update their registration information similar to an A record?  Is this something I could host for multiple customers? Multiple domains pointed to my IP, and use .htaccess or something similar to then send a request to the right page?

Comment: Sorry I didn't fully understand the question. Nathangiesbrecht's answer is more spot on.

I should also mention most major registrars have free domain forwarding that's probably the easiest was to accomplish the forwarding.

Comment: Thanks Dan. It does seem like Nathan's answer is closer to what I'm looking for.  Thanks for coming back in to say so, that's very helpful.